# How to verify the data next.js transmitted from the front-end in Socket.io, using decorators and pipelines

Tags: typescript

How to verify the data nest.js transmitted from the front-end in Socket.io, using decorators and pipelines

```
@UsePipes(new MsgPipe())
@SubscribeMessage("friendChatMessage")
async friendMessage(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket, @MessageBody() data: FriendMessageDto) {
    console.log(data);
    const { senderId, receiverId, content, type } = data;
```

}